# How to import numbers or protected signs from .txt?

Tags: import

I'm new here, so please apologize any formal errors.

I stumbled upon a somewhat simple problem. I want to import plain numbers or protected signs like `Pi`, `Cos`, `Sin` from .txt files. Somehow Mathematica does not understand that the read-in Pi is the protected `Pi` (= 3.14...). Even more simple examples seem not to work, e.g. reading in the number 5 from a .txt-file does not allow for using that 5 for further calculations.

My approach was:

1. Saving the sign/number in a txt file. E.g. Pi.txt contains just "Pi" (without quotation marks).
2. My Mathematica code is

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Code"];
x := Import["Pi.txt"]
f[t_] = Sin[t];
Evaluate[f[x]]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `ToExpression[Import["Pi.txt"]]`

Comment: The problem is that by default, the contents of a .txt file are read in as a string. Unfortunately, strings and  symbols look the same in output form. To check whether your imported expression is a string or a symbol you could do something like `x // InputForm`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works just fine. You saved my day.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE Joezens! Please consider registering your accounts, so that the upvotes you get on any future questions and answers add to the ones you received here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem description sounds as if you're in fact trying to import something into *Mathematica* that is more appropriately classified as a `.m` format, i.e., a `"Package"`. Let's say your text file contains the single entry

```
Pi
```

and its name is `Pi.txt` - then you could simply import it as follows:

```
variable = Import["Pi.txt", "Package"];
```

Now `variable` contains the value `Pi`. Moreover, your text file can be an entire *Mathematica* program such as

```
var1 = Sin[3];
var2 = 4;
var1 + var2
```

and its file name could be `prog.txt` - then in *Mathematica* you could do this:

```
Import["prog.txt", "Package"]

(* ==> 4 + Sin[3] *)

var1

(* ==> Sin[3] *)
```

The `"Package"` format is just a text file containing valid *Mathematica* expressions.

Things can be made even simpler if you adopt the standard extension for such *Mathematica* packages by calling the program file `prog.m` instead of `prog.txt`. Then the `Import` statement will be

```
Import["prog.m"]
```

and you're done.